# CSS animation to have divs overlap each other when hovered over and return to position after

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a hard time figuring this one out.
CSS vets help me out here :)

I want to have images (in the example they are denoted as divs with background colors)
overlap each other while hovered upon with animation and return to their respective place when the hover is over with the same animation.

In this example, you can see three sections of different colors move smoothly to the left or the right and then return to the position when the hover is off.
My current code:

```css
.images_parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.images_parent>* {
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
}


/*#i*/

#i:hover>* {
  z-index: 1;
}

#i:hover #a {
  margin-left: 20%;
  transition: margin-left 2s ease-in-out;
}

#i:hover #b {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#a {
  background-color: blue;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}

#c {
  background-color: blue;
}


/*#i*/


/*#i2*/

#i2 {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#i2:hover>* {
  z-index: 1;
}

#i2:hover #a2 {
  margin-left: -10%;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
}

#i2:hover #b2 {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#a2 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#b2 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#c2 {
  background-color: brown;
}


/*#i2*/


/*#i3*/

#i3 {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

#i3:hover>* {
  z-index: 1;
}

#i3:hover #a3 {
  margin-left: -20%;
  transition: margin-left 2s ease-in-out;
}

#i3:hover #b3 {
  margin-left: -10%;
}

#a3 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

#b3 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

#c3 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}


/*#i3*/
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="i" class="images_parent">
    <div id="a">image3</div>
    <div id="b">image3.1</div>
    <div id="c">image3.2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="i2" class="images_parent">
    <div id="a2">image2</div>
    <div id="b2">image2.1</div>
    <div id="c2">image2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="i3" class="images_parent">
    <div id="a3">image3</div>
    <div id="b3">image3.1</div>
    <div id="c3">image3.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbn2z7f6/

The problem is if we de-comment the `position:absolute` of `images_parent` then we can see that it does not look very beautiful.

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to do this correctly. Either with only forward animation or forward and backward animations. Both solutions would work for me.
Of course, having images retract would look nicer, but it doesn't matter too much.
Thank you.

Comment: Please go read [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, should be included directly in your question (in text form and properly formatted; as a stack snippet, in cases where that makes sense), and not just be dumped onto an external platform. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. But to get my point across this IS the minimal code I had to provide. There might be a better way to write this, but I did not think of a better way yet.

Comment: Yes; _my_ point was, that it needs to be included into the question. _“I would like to ask if anyone knows how to do this correctly.”_ - define “correctly” then, please? _“The problem is if we de-comment the "position:absolute" of "images_parent" then we can see that it does not look very beautiful.”_ - okay, so - _don’t_, then? Why is this a _problem_ to begin with?

Comment: You could probably keep the “main” images in normal flow, and only absolutely position the images that “move out” when hovered. But completely without absolute positioning, I don’t see how you would get that same effect of the images moving _over_ the other images, and not pushing them aside or “squishing” them.

Comment: Gotchas. Well if it wasn't too clearn of how I described it in the question then let me explain a bit more: Imagine having 3 images side by side. (My example - brown, blue and darkgreen). I cut each image into 3 pieces and put two of each behind the main one that is always shown. After I hover on one of the images other 2 jump out and envelop the whole space showing the whole image of the hovered one.

Comment: So the point in asking to avoid absolute positioning, would mainly be to have this whole element in normal flow, without having to explicitly set a margin anywhere to keep the following content at bay? Then make your outer container a _flex_ element, so that the inner three divs can arrange themselves next to each other. Leave the main image in normal flow (so that it determines the height the element will get), and position only the two “effect” images that are supposed to slide out to the sides absolutely.

Comment: I am not asking to avoid absolute positioning. I am using it and I ask you to use it as well if it helps you solve the issue. Its just that I've commented it in my question just to show how everything behaves behind the scenes so it's easier to see what I am asking.

Comment: _“if it helps you solve the issue”_ - what _is_ the issue then, that you want solved? What you have, apparently works, as long as you leave the absolute positioning in. So _why_ do you need a different way of doing this at all now? You can not just ask us for “the correct way” to do something like this, without giving us any criteria, for what would constitute “correct” in your opinion in the first place. There’s often multiple possible ways to solve such things.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't as clear. There's no correct way. If it was hard to imagine what I wanted, then its my bad, but the provided answer did what I tried to do. Hopefully I'll be better with asking the questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.top {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.images_parent {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.images_parent > * {
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
}

/*#i*/

#i:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 10px);
}

#i:hover #a {
  transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 20px);
}

#i:hover #b {
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 10px);
}

#a {
  background-color: blue;
}
#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  background-color: blue;
}
/*#i*/

#i2:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 10px);
}

#i2:hover #a2 {
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 20px);
}

#i2:hover #b2 {
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 10px);
}

/*#i2*/
#i2 {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#a2 {
  background-color: brown;
}
#b2 {
  background-color: brown;
}
#c2 {
  background-color: brown;
}
/*#i2*/

#i3:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 10px);
}

#i3:hover #a3 {
  transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 20px);
}

#i3:hover #b3 {
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 10px);
}

/*#i3*/
#i3 {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

#a3 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
#b3 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
#c3 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
/*#i3*/
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div id="i" class="images_parent">
    <div id="a">image3</div>
    <div id="b">image3.1</div>
    <div id="c">image3.2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="i2" class="images_parent">
    <div id="a2">image2</div>
    <div id="b2">image2.1</div>
    <div id="c2">image2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="i3" class="images_parent">
    <div id="a3">image3</div>
    <div id="b3">image3.1</div>
    <div id="c3">image3.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AMEN. Exactly what I imagined. Lets see if this works with images. Thank you.

Comment: @Zigzagas If you need additional help, Please let me know.

Comment: It works with images a well, btw :)